# firebase using claims in custom tokens

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-admin

firebase claims are used to control user permissions across firbase services like firestore rtdb storage .

I have 2 options 
[create-custom-tokens](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens) and [firebase auth custom claims](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/custom-claims)

is the claims in the custom-tokens are also limited to the same 1000 bytes size as the built-in option ??

can I just have an http trigger to the cloud function to create a custom token when needed from the frontend and use that token(that includes the custom claims) in any transaction that require user permission like upload a photo on a specific route. As the latest sdk allows to call the function without any boilerplate for HTTP client libraries is that feasible??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Claims on custom tokens are not size limited. But you can't exactly use custom tokens the way you've proposed. Only thing you can do with a custom token is to sign in with it on a client app: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens#sign_in_using_custom_tokens_on_clients

However, once you perform the sign in, you can use the resulting ID token to perform any operation you need. That is the ID token will have the custom claims set on it.